# How to give a class a clone method? What gets returned in a clone method?

Tags: java, function, methods, clone

This class must have a `clone()` method, so that copies of it can be made. I tried putting one in, but it is missing a return? What exactly do you return in a clone method?

This is the class I am trying to give a `clone()` method:

```
package planets;

public class Planet extends shape3D.Sphere {
    String myPrimaryGas;    
    public void setPrimaryGas(String primaryGas){
        myPrimaryGas = primaryGas;
    }
    public String getPrimaryGas(){
        return myPrimaryGas;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt at a clone method?

Comment: Have you tried to google that? There's event a Wikipedia article about this topic :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_(Java_method)

Comment: Shallow or deep clone ? does `shape3D.Sphere` support cloning (implements Cloneable ?

Comment: Not sure if shallow or deep. It just says "All of your methods need a clone() method to create copies"

Answer (score 1):

What your clone does (in java) is essentially create a second object, of type Planet (in this case), and copies all the values so that you have two identical objects, the new one, and 'this'.

So your clone would be something like

```
public Planet clone (){
    Planet p = new Planet (myPrimaryGas);
    return p;
}
```

or in your case, it seems like you have no constructor defined, so this :

```
public Planet clone (){
    Planet p = new Planet ();
    p.setPrimaryGas(myPrimaryGas);
    return p;
}
```

Keep in mind, you want a "deep copy" ... meaning you need to call clone for all objects inside of this one.  The only reason I can use "myPrimaryGas" and not "myPrimaryGas.clone()" is because Strings are (almost) a primitive type

Comment: Often in order to make cloning works, involves a private constructor to really directly assign things.

Comment: Also, the `real` reason you don't need to clone `String`s is because `String`s in java are immutable.

Comment: Yes, there won't be any issues of modifying the object from two locations.  For most intents Strings in java can be handled as if they were integers

Comment: `"12" + "3" == "123": false`. `12 + 3 == 15: true`

Comment: @Cruncher I agree with your initial comment but it happens that `"12" + "3" == "123"` is true...

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting ...  Although his point is still valid :P